# vuejs filtered for status type

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Regards, I have a question that the function in the photo is filtering according to the inputt value, and I also want to list the 0 status_type values ​​among the values ​​from the api, how can I write a function for this?

[image]

VUE 3

Regards, I have a question that the function in the photo is filtering according to the inputt value, and I also want to list the 0 status_type values ​​among the values ​​from the api, how can I write a function for this?

VUE 3

Comment: Please don't post a code as an image.

Comment: `return this.applications.filter(item => item.status_type === 0)`

Comment: I have one more question. Name and surname come in 2 different values ​​from API, for example: Asd.name or asd.surname, how can I do this for both name and surname during filtering?

The value written to the input will be filtered

Comment: When fetching the data from the API, you can `map` the result and create a new `toBeFiltered` attribute/key in your items which will be equal to `(asd.name + asd.surname).toLowerCase()` and then in your computed property you will search inside this field.